# Is there a way to get user input appended to a table in spotfire?

Tags: r, ironpython, spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I have a table `Table1` in with some context information in spotfire (dcube) that has something like:

```
Name      Food    Seating
XYZ     Seafood   outdoors
```

I have created a test area with two buttons `Yes` and `No`.
The user will select a record in `Table1` and click on one of the buttons, and it should populate another table `Table2` with an added column `Preference` with the output as the following:

```
Name      Food    Seating   Preference
XYZ     Seafood   outdoor     Yes
```

Where the value for the `preference` column is populated based on whether the user clicked `Yes` or `No`. when user sets a preference for another record in `Table1`, it should append as a row in `Table2`.

Is this possible via R or IronPython without using TERR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python and write back to a database to achieve this. But I'm not sure of good/efficient way to do this without an external data source.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import DatabaseDataSource
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import DatabaseDataSourceSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualTypeIdentifiers
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import IndexSet
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import RowSelection
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataValueCursor
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataSelection
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataPropertyClass

rowCount = Document.ActiveDataTableReference.RowCount
rowsToInclude = IndexSet(rowCount,True)

#Get a cursor to the two columns we want to use. cursor1 is for the key column and cursor2 is for the column selected by the user input

cursor1 = DataValueCursor.Create[int](Document.ActiveDataTableReference.Columns["ProductID"])
cursor2 = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(Document.ActiveDataTableReference.Columns[whichCol])

#The following section will add a column to the database table using the name specified by the user. This assumes a column with this name does not already exist.

sqlCommand = "ALTER TABLE Products ADD " + colName + " varchar(50);"
dbsettings = DatabaseDataSourceSettings( "System.Data.SqlClient","Server=localhost;Database=myDB;UID=myuser;PWD=mypass",sqlCommand)
ds = DatabaseDataSource(dbsettings)
newDataTable = Document.Data.Tables.Add("temp",ds)
Document.Data.Tables.Remove(newDataTable)

#The following section will update the specified column in the database using the key column in the where clause
sqlStr=""
for  row in  Document.ActiveDataTableReference.GetRows(rowsToInclude,cursor1,cursor2):
   value1 = cursor1.CurrentValue
   value2 = cursor2.CurrentValue
   sqlStr = sqlStr +  "UPDATE Products SET " + colName + "='" + value2 + "' WHERE (ProductID=" + str(value1)  + ");"

sqlCommand = "UPDATE Products "  + sqlStr + ";"
dbsettings = DatabaseDataSourceSettings( "System.Data.SqlClient",
"Server=localhost;Database=Northwind;UID=myuser;PWD=mypass",sqlStr)
ds = DatabaseDataSource(dbsettings)
newDataTable = Document.Data.Tables.Add("temp",ds)
Document.Data.Tables.Remove(newDataTable)
```

The above is from [Tibco Spotfire](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-write-back-database-tibco-spotfirer-using-ironpython-scripting) I've used it as a template to create a ticket system in spotfire using tables in a SQL server.

Comment: Thank you for posting a potential solution. It is also fine if I can write it to an external database. In your example, is `dbsettings` the one where you specify the connection string and authentication to the external db?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The example is connecting to an SQL database. (example is the Northwind SQL database thats normally used in examples for SQL )